# My sticky header is not working, why is this?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sticky

For a school project, I need to build a site. One of the things required is a header and preferably, a sticky one. 
I went to w3schools and I found a tutorial for it, and I put it in my project, but well, the header is definitely not sticking. After about an hour of searching, I gave up. Can maybe one of you help me? (I'm just a beginning high school computer science kid, my code ain't that brilliant or whatever)

I have tried changing the id's and classes of the code I already had. And I've tried to look for mistakes, but without success.

**Html**

```html
<header class="header" id="myHeader">
  <h1>My Page</h1>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```css
.top-container {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background: #555;
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 102px;
}

#openNav{
    text-align: left
}
```

**Javascript**

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

So, the header exists and looks like a header, the only thing is; it doesn't stick at all.

Comment: Hey, welcome to the community! Just a heads up -- please don't post pictures of code, just post the actual code! It helps a ton for users who want to copy what you've got into a boilerplate to see the issue for themselves!

Comment: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/0e9nsdk5/ . Does your script run **after** the header exists? Try putting your script tag right before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: Ah, found the problem. accidentally put the script tag in <head> instead of <body>. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @blex mentioned, the provided code seems to work. Anyways, I just wanted to point out that you can also make a sticky header without any javascript, simply with the css property `position: fixed`.

```css
.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

heres a fully functional [codepen example](https://codepen.io/dcts/pen/jOOYvrM).

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, myself :))

Accidentally put the script tag in `<head>` instead of `<body>`